# Comparing generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a Generic Binary Search Tree. I need to compare two generic types. How to do it, assuming the the user has implemented `IComparable` in T class.

```
private void Insert(T newData, ref Node<T> currentRoot)
{
    if (currentRoot == null)
    {
        currentRoot = new Node<T>(newData);
        return;
    }
    if (newData <= currentRoot.data) //doesn't work, need equivalent functionality
         Insert(newData, ref currentRoot.lChild);
    else
         Insert(newData,  ref currentRoot.rChild); 
}
```

Comment: doesn't `newData.CompareTo(currentRoot.data)` work ?

Comment: works only with `where T: IComparable<T>` as @BrokenGlass pointed out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add a generic constraint `where T: IComparable<T>` to your method to make the [`CompareTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx) method available to instances of your type `T`.

```
private void Insert(T newData, ref Node<T> currentRoot) where T: IComparable<T>
{
  //...
}
```

Then you can use:

```
if (newData.CompareTo(currentRoot.data) <= 0) 
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `where` clause, i.e.

```
class Node<T> where T : IComparable
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: This answer is incomplete, simply providing a constraint does not allow the line of code the user attempted. Fortunately, BrokenGlass added an appropriate example solution.

Comment: I see it. My C# is a bit rusty ;)